# Spring Security : update Granted Authorities of another logged in user

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm currently using SpringSecurity with my own implementation of `UserDetailsService`, getting users and their rights from the DB. 
The problem I'm facing now is the following :

- user A logs in
- user B modifies user A's rights in DB
- user A should have it's rights updated without having to reconnect

I'm having trouble to force `UserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(String)` to be recalled. Any idea on how I could do this ?

Answer (score 0):

While I am also looking for a perfect solution to this problem. Here is one workaround:

> Identify the user rights for your requirements. For example X rights,
>   added (to user A) in DB, by user B for which you do not want to force
>   a re-login by A.  Do not club these X rights with spring granted
>   authorities, instead bind these X rights in user A's session using a
>   filter/interceptor which is invoked on every request.